# How to use deleteMessage to get a Discord bot to clear a messge after () minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

```
{
setTimeout(function()
{
   deleteMessage()
}, 120000);
}
```

Trying to get my bot to delete a message after () minutes of it being sent what would I use to do this. If needed, the library I used was https://github.com/hydrabolt/Discord.JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this function in a `setTimeout`, like you currently have.

http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#deletemessage-message-options-callback

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with discord.js, but from the looks of things it's a method on your client object. So probably something along the lines of `client.deleteMessage(message)`

Comment: @ Joundill Yes Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

```
bot.on("message", function(message)
  {
  setTimeout(function()
  {
  bot.deleteMessage(message)
  }, 120000);
});
```

This is what it ended up looking like, thank you **Joundill** for the help.